# Sort strangeness with ":"

Tags: unix, sorting

I tried to sort the following file with `LC_ALL=C ; sort test.txt` and I get the folowing result.

```
:
0
1
1:02
10:2
1:2
1:20
1:2:0
2
2:1
2:2
2:2
```

Note that `:` is sorted before `0`. However, `1:2` is sorted after `10:2` ????????

What is going on?

Please feel free to try yourself and experience the strangeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon in your command:

```
LC_ALL=C ; sort test.txt
```

And you will then see the output you expect.